# Can I be selective on what rows I join on in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose I have two tables, `people` and `emails`. `emails` has a `person_id`, an `address`, and an `is_primary`:

```
people:
  id

emails:
  person_id
  address
  is_primary
```

To get all email addresses per person, I can do a simple join:

```
select * from people join emails on people.id = emails.person_id
```

What if I only want (at most) one row from the right table for each row in the left table? And, if a particular person has multiple emails and one is marked as `is_primary`, is there a way to prefer which row to use when joining?

So, if I have

```
people:     emails:
------      -----------------------------------------
| id |      | id | person_id | address | is_primary |
------      -----------------------------------------
|  1 |      |  1 |         1 |  a@b.c  |    true    |
|  2 |      |  2 |         1 |  b@b.c  |    false   |
|  3 |      |  3 |         2 |  c@b.c  |    true    |
|  4 |      |  4 |         4 |  d@b.c  |    false   |
------      -----------------------------------------
```

is there a way to get this result:

```
------------------------------------------------
| people.id | emails.id | address | is_primary |
------------------------------------------------
|         1 |         1 |  a@b.c  |    true    |
|         2 |         3 |  c@b.c  |    true    | // chosen over b@b.c because it's primary
|         3 |      null |  null   |    null    | // no email for person 3
|         4 |         4 |  d@b.c  |    false   | // no primary email for person 4
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN is not "only one"; it is every row from the left regardless of if there are any matching "on the right". If there are multiple on the right, there will still be multiple copies of the data from the matching left row; if there are none on the right, you will still have one copy of the left row's data, but with NULL for any fields from the right.

Comment: If person with id=4 has a second email that is also not primary - which one would you want to show? Another case: What if a person has two primary emails? And what is the promary key of the `emails` table?

Comment: I would always choose is_primary=true over is_primary=false since I want to email their best email addresses. The primary key of emails is emails.id, I was just too lazy to type all the columns. I'll add it in. If a person has two primary emails then either one (the first by id is fine) and if they have mulitple non-primary ids then the first is fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

You got it a bit wrong, how left/right joins work.

This join

```
select * from people join emails on people.id = emails.person_id
```

will get you every column from both tables for all records that match your `ON` condition.

The left join

```
select * from people left join emails on people.id = emails.person_id
```

will give you every record from people, regardless if there's a corresponding record in emails or not. When there's not, the columns from the emails table will just be `NULL`.

If a person has multiple emails, multiple records will be in the result for this person. Beginners often wonder then, why the data has duplicated.

If you want to restrict the data to the rows where `is_primary` has the value `1`, you can do so in the `WHERE` clause when you're doing an inner join (your first query, although you ommitted the `inner` keyword).

When you have a left/right join query, you have to put this filter in the `ON` clause. If you would put it in the `WHERE` clause, you would turn the left/right join into an inner join implicitly, because the `WHERE` clause would filter the `NULL` rows that I mentioned above. Or you could write the query like this:

```
select * from people left join emails on people.id = emails.person_id
where (emails.is_primary = 1 or emails.is_primary is null)
```

---

EDIT after clarification:

Paul Spiegel's answer is good, therefore my upvote, but I'm not sure if it performs well, since it has a dependent subquery. So I created this query. It may depend on your data though. Try both answers.

```
select 
p.*,
coalesce(e1.address, e2.address) AS address
from people p
left join emails e1 on p.id = e1.person_id and e1.is_primary = 1 
left join (
    select person_id, address 
    from emails e 
    where id = (select min(id) from emails where emails.is_primary = 0 and emails.person_id = e.person_id)
) e2 on p.id = e2.person_id
```

Comment: I'll edit my question. Essentially, I want a person's primary email address if there is one, or any other email address for the person otherwise. I can't figure out better wording that "prefer is_primary=true", if that helps.

Comment: I get an error: "Unknown column 'e2.address'". You need to remove the alias `as e_id`

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery with `LIMIT 1` in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN:

```sql
select * 
from people p
left join emails e
    on  e.person_id = p.id
    and e.id = (
        select e1.id
        from emails e1
        where e1.person_id = e.person_id
        order by e1.is_primary desc, -- true first
                 e1.id -- If e1.is_primary is ambiguous
        limit 1
    )
order by p.id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e03f/6)

Comment: It's a good answer, although I'm not sure about performance. In case you're interested, I provided an alternative, which might as well perform worse than yours. Might depend on OP's data. Anyway, +1

Comment: @fancyPants - an index on emails(person_id, is_primary) would support the subquery. And MySQL should cache the subquery result for each person_id. However - depending on data distribution and indexes, multiple times nested sunqueries with min/max search might be faster.